# Android getViewModelStoreOwner for AndroidViewModel, no zero argument constructor error

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

I was using the beta version of the navigation component and my code was working fine, I then swapped back to the latest non beta version and it stopped working, but from what I can see I wasn't using anything beta-ish :-)

I want to scope view models to navigation graphs I do this by getting the nav controller store owner, this works for ViewModel but not for AndroidViewModel, when trying it throws an error because it expects a no zero argument constructor, which isn't the case for AndroidViewModel but as mentioned above this works in the beta version,

```
private ViewModelStoreOwner getStoreOwner() {

        NavController navController = Navigation
                .findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.root_navigator_fragment);
        return navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.root_navigator);

}
```

**Use it with**

```
singleCardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getStoreOwner()).get(SingleCardViewModel.class);
```

so a few ways I can make this work is

1) swap the android view model for a normal view model, this can be done for most however some view models require application for my database calls,

2) I could swap them for view models and then make factories to pass it the application,

3) I can replace the getStoreOwner for the fragment by just passing 'this' instead of getStoreOwner but that probably means more testing to make sure its not holding values

4) Continue using the beta version, I'd rather avoid this if possible

none of these are really ideal, shouldn't this just work? am i doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: went back to the beta version just to check and this definitely doesnt have this problem

Comment: Even though you can get application context with `AndroidViewModel` I wouldn't recommend doing anything with a context in the ViewModel, Why not delegate things to the Activity or Fragment and use it from there?

Comment: fairly sure using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel is tied to the life cycle so is fine to use in this instance in fact i think this is what it was built for, regardless i use it to initialise the database in a repository so cant be helped

Comment: It's a version mismatch between `androidx.core`, `androidx.fragment`, and `androidx.lifecycle`.